# Is the undetected_chromedriver package safe to use?

Tags: undetected-chromedriver

Is the undetected_chromedriver package safe to use?
Is this a widely used and trusted package that you would happily pip install and run?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I believe so I have used chromedriver and undetected_chromedriver prevents websites from detecting you are a bot well it at least just makes it hard.